# ng2-carouselamos does not show the last items on mobile screens

Tags: responsive

I am using ng2-carouselamos present here on StackBlits:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fssh6z?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

***when I change the width of ng2-carouselamos div (ex. [width]="850") it stops to slide to last items***

it has 7 items with ABCD1 to ABCD7 but it stops on ABCD5 item on mobile screen.

**It does not show the last 2 items on mobile screen.**

I did try everything but facing the same issue. Please let me know how to solve this.

Thanks!

Comment: Something went wrong with your image. By the way, can you show us what you've tried ? (code)

Comment: the same code i tried on desktop view is good but carousel stops when i try to see on responsive view using chrome.

Comment: Sorry for forget to write that when i changed the width of ng2-carouselamos to '850' (according to my design) it stops the last items to slide.